# Ruby/Rails - Is there an easy way to make hard-coded HTML symbols html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-safe

In my view I want to display some right double angle quotes in my link.

Before Rails 3, this worked:

`<%= link_to "&raquo; #{@category.name}", some_path %>`

Now what should I do if I want to specify the `&raquo;` as html_safe but not the rest of the link's text?

In other words I do *not* want to do this:

`<%= link_to "&raquo; #{@category.name}".html_safe, some_path %>`
I do not want the `@category.name` treated as html_safe.

This produces the desired result:

`<%= link_to "&raquo;".html_safe + " #{@category.name}", some_path %>`

However, if I do this:

`<%= link_to "#{@category.name}" + "&raquo;".html_safe, some_path %>`

The output of the angle quotes is not treated as safe.  I see `&raquo;` on my page and not ».

Why?

I tried extracting `"&raquo;".html_safe` to a helper method with the same results.

Is there a way to easily designate hard coded text/symbols as HMTL safe in Rails 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation I often explicitly escape the unsafe part:

```
"&raquo; #{h @category.name}".html_safe
```

Comment: I would remove the "often" bit here, or replace it with always, or indicate that sanitizer could be used as well.

Comment: h explicitly escapes html. See [html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape).

Comment: It looks like this is the right answer...but I don't like it.  I wish there was a way to specify a list of characters/html as "ok", or at least a way for hard coded characters/html/symbols in views to be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the whole string is html_safe...

I'd recommend to try this:

```
   "&raquo; #{h @cagegory.name}".html_safe
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Note that the category name is not treated safely, and the system becomes vulnerable to JS injection.

Comment: good point! yes, if name is a user accessible attribute, then we need an "h" before the category name to escape HTML! (I'll add that)